# How to separate a String on multiple delimiters?

Tags: java, string, divide

I have string `"1000:2000,3000"` and I need to divide it into 3 strings so something like that:

```
"1000"
"2000"  
"3000"
```

My code looks like:

```
int datas = 0;
String item = "";
String data = "";
String pocet = "";
List<String> items = "1000:2000,3000";
for (int ii = 0; ii < items.size(); ii++) {
    System.out.println(items.get(ii));
    int delkaid = items.get(ii).indexOf(":");
    int delkadat = items.get(ii).indexOf(",") - items.get(ii).indexOf(":");
    int delkapoctu = items.get(ii).length() - items.get(ii).indexOf(",");


    for (int ite = 0; ite < delkaid; i++) {
        item = item + items.get(ii).charAt(ite) + "";
    }

    for (int ite = 0; ite < delkadat; i++) {
        data = data + items.get(ii).charAt(items.get(ii).indexOf(":") + 1 + ite) + "";
    }

    for (int ite = 0; ite < delkapoctu; i++) {
        pocet = pocet + items.get(ii).charAt(items.get(ii).indexOf(",") + 1 + ite) + "";
    }
    datas = Integer.valueOf(data);

}
```

But I have some mistake in the code.

Comment: You can use `String.split(":");` You don't need any of that code to accomplish this.

Comment: String[] parts = string.split(":");

Comment: For completeness, you'll actually need to either (a) split it twice, or (b) split on a regex. Which is what Java's `String.split` does, e.g., `:|,`

Comment: **Wow there are so many people that can't read for comprehension!** The answer isn't `.split(":");` read the questions requirements again!

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I, at least, answered before the question was reformatted, and it was extremely difficult to see the difference in punctuation.

Comment: @chrylis so did I and I saw the `,`, so did others!

Answer (score 6):

Your code doesnt compile due to the assignment of a `String` to your `List` but you could split on an [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

```
String[] array = str.split(":|,");
```

A corresponding integer array of equal size can be used to hold the integer values. These can be processed in a basic `for` loop

Answer (score 4):

Here is a [link to a running example](https://ideone.com/TERcHi):

```
public static void main (final String[] args)
{
    final String s = "1000:2000,3000";
    final String[] a = s.split("[:,]");
    for (final String n : a)
    {
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
1000
2000
3000
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method:

```
String[] tokens = str.split(":|,");
```

Answer (score 0):

this will split numbers on any delimiters

```
String numbers[] = line.split("\\D+");
```